# Create Graph from User Form on Website

Tags: jquery, html, graph, charts

I'd like to display a graph on my site that has two bars or lines.

The Y axis will be £ between 0 and 1000
The X axis will be time in months between 0 and 6

One line will plot a constant £500 between month 0 and 6

The second line will plot the amount added by the user between month 0 and 6

I have never used graphs on a website before, only in Excel etc.

Can anyone point me in the direction of a JQuery plugin or snippet of code that does this kind of thing?

Many thanks!
dvent

Comment: [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) is one of the most commonly used charting libraries, and it's easy and well supported. There are many others as well, like Google Charts etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you will most likely be wanting to look at some third party data visualization controls/plugins such as the ones made by DevExpress or Telerik.

If however you don't want to pay a lot of money for what will be just a small amount of functionality then consider using Google's Chart Tools:

https://developers.google.com/chart/

Since they are pretty cool and free to use...

Comment: Thanks Neil - that's what I need. Not sure why the question has been closed - seems valid to me!